# One question on Matrix Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

Assume $\hat{M}_1, \hat{M}_2, \hat{T}_{11}, \hat{T}_{12}, \hat{T}_{21}, \hat{T}_{22}$ are $2\times 2$ matrix. 
And $a, b, A, B, C, D$ are all numbers, satisfying the following relation:

\begin{align}
\left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  \hat{M}_1 \\ \hat{M}_2
  \end{array} \right)
\left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  a \\ b
  \end{array} \right)
= \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  \hat{T}_{11} & \hat{T}_{12} \\ \hat{T}_{21} & \hat{T}_{22}
  \end{array} \right)
\left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  A \\ B\\ C \\ D
  \end{array} \right).
\end{align}

If we define 
$\begin{align}
\left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  A \\ B
  \end{array} \right)
= \hat{S} 
\left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  a \\ b
  \end{array} \right)
\end{align}$, where S is a $2\times2$ matrix.
There is definitely one equation between $\hat{S}$ and $\hat{M}_i$, $\hat{T}_{ij}$.

But my question here is: does the expression of S have any relation
with Det($\check{M}$). 
\begin{align}
\check{M}\equiv\left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  \hat{T}_{11} & \hat{T}_{12} \\ \hat{T}_{21} & \hat{T}_{22}
  \end{array} \right).
\end{align}

**Thanks anyway, I've solved the problem.**

If we redefine $\check{M}\equiv[\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3,\phi_4]$, where $\phi_i$ is $4\times1$ matrix. And $\left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  \hat{M}_1 \\ \hat{M}_2
  \end{array} \right) \equiv [\psi_1,\psi_2]$.

According to Cramer's rule, 
\begin{align*}
A&=\frac{Det[(a\psi_1+b\psi_2,\phi_2,\phi_3,\phi_4)]}{Det[\check{M}]}\\
 &= a\frac{Det[(\psi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3,\phi_4)]}{Det[\check{M}]}
  +b\frac{Det[(\psi_2,\phi_2,\phi_3,\phi_4)]}{Det[\check{M}]}.
\end{align*}

So $\hat{S}_{11} = \frac{Det[(\psi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3,\phi_4)]}{Det[\check{M}]}$. Same way, we can derive out the expression of $\hat{S}$.

Comment: I can't see how the dimensions of your products work. Also, how are you defining the matrix $\check{M}$?

Comment: @hjhjhj57 $\check{M}$ is a $4\times4$ matrix here. I just reedit the post, where "$\hat{\square}"$ stands for $2\times2$ matrix, "$\check{\square}$" stands for $4\times4$ matrix. I think my question has relation with Cramer's rule, but I'm not familiar with this.